# Convert between priority of two systems

Tags: algorithm

I have two "systems" the with some records.

**System A** has record with priority from 1-4 (lets say minSystemAP = 4, maxSystemAP = 1).

**System A Priority:**
4 - Low, 3- Medium, 2 - High, 1 - Critical.

**System B** has record with priority from 1-10 (lets say minSystemBP = 10, maxSystemBP = 1).

**System A Priority:** 1-Minimum, 5- Medium, 10- High.

I'm trying to create record from System B in System A.

How can i "convert" between the priority of SystemA to SystemB?

Meaning, Record with priority 10 in System B will be record with priority ~ 4 in System A.

and record with priority 5 in System B will be record with priority ~ 2 in System A.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping must assign multiple priorities in SystemB to one priority in SystemA.

E.g.:

A    1    1    2    2    2    3    3    3    4     4

B    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9     10

This mapping-function would meet your requirements and can simply be implemented as integer-division:

```
int prioA = prioB / 3 + 1;
```